# App breaks due to loading two services

Tags: angularjs

I'm using two services right now, but only one works depending on which one is loaded in. If I only load **one** service, it works. One or the other. The services are also included in my `app.js`.

One service:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('nutricia.services', [])
    .service('LoginService', function($http) {


        var login = function (apiUrl, apiKey, loginID, password) {
         return $http({
             method: "POST",
             url: apiUrl + "?apiKey=" + encodeURIComponent(apiKey) + "&loginID=" + encodeURIComponent(loginID) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password) 
           });
        };

        var logout = function (apiUrl, apiKey, UID) {
          return $http({
              method: "POST",
              url: apiUrl + "?apiKey=" + encodeURIComponent(apiKey) + "&UID=" + encodeURIComponent(UID)
          });
        };

        return {
          login: login,
          logout: logout
        };

    })
})();
```

Other service:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('nutricia.services', [])
        .service('KwaaltjestestService', function($http, $q) {

            var getKwaaltjes = function (params) {
              var deferred = $q.defer();

               $http({
                     method: 'GET',
                     url: 'https://www.nutriciavoorjou.nl/mvc/allergytest/' + params
                   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                       deferred.resolve(response.data);
                     }, function errorCallback(response) {
                     });
                   return deferred.promise;
            };

            return {
                getKwaaltjes: getKwaaltjes
            };

        })
})();
```

One controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('nutricia.login', [])
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function(LoginService) {


    });

})();
```

Other controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('nutricia.kwaaltjestest', [])
    .controller('KwaaltjestestCtrl', function(KwaaltjestestService) {


    })

})();
```

Index.html:

```
<script src="components/kwaaltjestest/kwaaltjestest.controller.js"></script>
<script src="components/login/login.controller.js"></script>

<script src="shared/services/login.service.js"></script>
<script src="shared/services/kwaaltjestest.service.js"></script>
```

Why is this happening? If I remove the `kwaaltjestest`, the `login` service will work. If I remove the `login` service, the `kwaaltjestest` service will work. Changing the loading order in `index.html` does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have

```
angular.module('nutricia.services', [])
```

In both files it is redefining the module and so one service is lost (whichever was defined on the first "version" of this module)  Angular won't warn you of this redefinition of the module luckily it's an easy fix in the second service loaded in your html instead of including the dependencies in the .module call just omit those to get the existing module and add new services to it.

```
angular.module('nutricia.services')
```

many developers will just define the module in one file and "get" it in all the ones that are actually adding things to it to be clear about where it is defined.

Comment: Thank you! This is an issue I have never stumbled upon before and is a great lesson for me.

Comment: @J.Doe no problem, would suggest looking over this guide of conventions too, lots of good tips to help avoid common pitfalls https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1